# Focus Omnibar in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I bring the Omnibar into focus in Google Chrome after a given event?

I've heard API support for the Omnibar is rather limited, but is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Chrome Extensions Omnibox Documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html):

> The omnibox API allows you to register a keyword with Google Chrome's address bar, which is also known as the omnibox.

Unfortunately, that's the extent of what's possible. You can only specify the response to the user's query with a keyword you've registered, nothing else. [Their discussion groups confirm](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/search?q=omnibox&scoring=d)  that there are no current plans to add any more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> on a Mac, although it does type out?